# What is the meaning of this lines said by Grace?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Drama Movie: Short Term (2013), Grace say this words to Jayden about her mom's boyfriends.

> Whenever I was drawing portraits of, you know, those guys, I would
>   always take forever. **30, 40 minutes just stringing them along, saying,
>   oh, I've just got to do a couple more shadows, or, I'm just fixing the
>   nose**. I don't know why I did that.

**couple more shadows** is it means [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow) or Is it idiom?

Another doubt is What does mean by "**stringing them along**" ?

I am so confused. please explain this lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, there's no specific reference for this but the shadows would refer to the shadows on the portrait, as part of the [drawing](http://www.dummies.com/art-center/performing-arts/drawing/drawing-light-and-shadows/) process.

'**Stringing them along**' just means to keep them waiting - See [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/string%20along)
for example..